# Can I access objects (button or hyperlink) within a templatefield in a Gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to access an object (hyperlink or button) within a templatefield in a gridview.
How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you're binding data to it, you'll want to look at doing that inside the [RowDataBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx) event.

Here's an example of how to retrieve a control within a Template Field:

**.aspx:**

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" Runat="server" 
    OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Template Field">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="btnTest" Runat="server" /> 
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

**Code-behind:**

```
void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        Button btnTest = (Button)e.Row.FindControl("btnTest");
        btnTest.Text = "I'm in a Template Field";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use it on `RowDataBound` or click event of your template control like

```
TextBox txtTemp= (TextBox )e.Row[e.RowIndex].FindControl("yourControlName");
string someText=txtTemp.Text;
```